# Conditionally exclude/include properties from dto using .NET 5 Web API (Field Level Access)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

I'm developing a .NET 5 Web Api with the default `System.Text.Json` model binding.
For several dtos I need something like this:

```
public class MyDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PublicDetails { get; set; }
        [IncludeForRoles("admin", "staff")]
        public string InternalDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

If a user with a role other than "admin" or "staff" calls the endpoint which returns the above mentioned dto, the property "InternalDetails" should be ignored on model binding and not be added to the serialized dto.
Is there a standard way to do this? If not, how could I implement this behavior manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a kind of workaround which meets the requirements but has the following disadvantages:

- Data which is not needed is loaded from the database (Automapper's `.ProjectTo` cannot be used)
- Data is modified after mapping (Injection of services into Automapper's `Profile` is not possible, see [here](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#asp-net-core-and-automapper-extensions-microsoft-dependencyinjection))
- Two attributes have to be added to every property which should be ignored in some cases.

You see, this is not a beautiful and elegant solution. Feel free to suggest a better one!

The attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class IncludeForRolesAttribute : Attribute
{
    public IncludeForRolesAttribute(params string[] roleNames)
    {
        RoleNames = roleNames;
    }
    public string[] RoleNames { get; }
}
```

The Automapper Mapping Action:

```
public class RoleBasedSetNullAction<TSource, TDestination> : IMappingAction<TSource, TDestination>
{
    private readonly ITokenAccessor _tokenAccessor;

    public RoleBasedSetNullAction(ITokenAccessor tokenAccessor)
    {
        _tokenAccessor = tokenAccessor ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(tokenAccessor));
    }

    public void Process(TSource source, TDestination destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties().Where(
        prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(IncludeForRolesAttribute)));

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            IncludeForRolesAttribute attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<IncludeForRolesAttribute>();
            if (!_tokenAccessor.UserRoles.Intersect(attr.RoleNames).Any())
            {
                prop.SetValue(destination, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The DTO:

```
public class MyDto : BaseEntityDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public string PublicDetails { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
    [IncludeForRoles("admin", "staff")]
    public string InternalDetails { get; set; }
}
```

The Automapper Mapping Profile:

```
public class MyDtoMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MyDtoMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDto>()
            .AfterMap<RoleBasedSetNullAction<MyEntity, MyDto>>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that somebody downvotes my answer to my own question after days without a suitable answer to the question. I just wanted to share my approach and I clearly labeled it as workaround and mentioned the disadvantages...

Answer (score 2):

There is a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute which takes a condition that will ignore properties if they are null or default.

Assuming that you will know the role in the controller, only get the InternalDetails information if they have the relevant role and keep it as null if not. This also reduces query times as you aren't getting information you don't need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great not to have to load the properties that a certain role is not allowed to see from the database. Unfortunately I've not yet found a way do conditionally exclude properties from entity framework mapping. Any idea?

Comment: I hadn't fully considered the fact that what your actually receiving is a db table with columns. What you are after here is column level security which doesn't have an implementation in EF from my knowledge but this post does give some good ideas: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229949/how-to-handle-field-level-acces-security-when-using-entity-framework

Comment: Thanks for the link. The mentioned approach does not work in my case because I don't identify the current user via windows groups or sql login but via jwt access token which is not yet present at the execution of `OnModelCreating`

Comment: I've created a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67474429/property-column-level-access-in-entity-framework-core) for the ef core issue

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) library for serialization and implement custom [ContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm)  to dynamically decide which fields to serialize.

Comment: Newtonsoft.JSON has been deprecated since .Net Core 3.1 in favour of System.Text.Json.

Comment: Actually It's not deprecated, it is just not included by default (mostly for performance reasons). Since ASP.NET Core has pluggable architecture you can use whatever serializer you want and Newtonsoft.JSON can be a reasonable choice for many projects

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Rem. Unfortunately it is not an option in this project to switch to Newtonsoft.Json.