# Property/Column level access in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, authorization, .net-5, role-base-authorization

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67455754/conditionally-exclude-include-properties-from-dto-using-net-5-web-api) question I asked for a way to achieve Property/Field level access in .NET 5. One idea was to do the magic in the EF Core configuration, so that only those properties are loaded from database the current user has access to. In the second step the empty property will the excluded from the dto using the `JsonIgnore` attribute with default condition. I've tried my best to implement the logic in the `OnModelCreating` hook of the context using a custom property attribute on the entity properties:

```
public class MyEntity : BaseEntity
{
   [IncludeForRoles(RoleNames.Staff)]
   public string InternalDetails { get; private set; }
}

public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid>, IMyContext
{

   private readonly ITokenAccessor _tokenAccessor;

   public MyContext(
            DbContextOptions options,
            ITokenAccessor tokenAccessor) : base(options)
   {
        _tokenAccessor = tokenAccessor;
   }

   [...]

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
   {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(UserConfiguration).Assembly);

        foreach (Type type in MyContextUtility.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            MethodInfo ignoreFlagMethod = MyContextUtility.SetRoleBasedIgnoreFlagMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            ignoreFlagMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { builder, _tokenAccessor.UserRoles });
        }
    }
}

public static class MyContextUtility
{
    private static IList<Type> _entityTypeCache;

    public static IList<Type> GetEntityTypes()
    {
        if (_entityTypeCache != null)

        {
            return _entityTypeCache.ToList();
        }

        Assembly assembly = typeof(BaseEntity).Assembly;

        _entityTypeCache = (from t in assembly.DefinedTypes
                            where t.BaseType == typeof(BaseEntity)
                            select t.AsType()).ToList();

        return _entityTypeCache;
    }

    public static readonly MethodInfo SetRoleBasedIgnoreFlagMethod
        = typeof(MyContextUtility).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Single(t => t.IsGenericMethod && t.Name == nameof(SetRoleBasedIgnoreFlag));

    public static void SetRoleBasedIgnoreFlag<T>(ModelBuilder builder, IList<string> userRoles) where T : BaseEntity
    {
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> props = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(
            prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(IncludeForRolesAttribute)));

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            IncludeForRolesAttribute attr = prop.GetCustomAttribute<IncludeForRolesAttribute>();
            if (!userRoles.Intersect(attr.RoleNames).Any())
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Adding ignore flag for type '{typeof(T).Name}' and property {prop.Name}.");
                builder.Entity<T>().Ignore(prop.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ITokenAccessor` provides access to the jwt access token of the current user.
The above code does not work because `OnModelCreating` is executed before a user is logged in and that's the reason why `_tokenAccessor.UserRoles` is always empty at this point.

Is there a way to achieve the property/column based access in entity framework core? I spent hours researching but unfortunately couldn't find a solution. And I am very surprised that property/column based access should be such an unusual requirement.

Comment: Do you use Automapper or just let entities go via network? Asking because you are moving in wrong direction.

Comment: I use automapper to map the entities to dtos

Comment: Well, why you do not create Automapper configurations which eliminates not needed properties?

Comment: This is one option, yes. But how to inject the ITokenAccessor into the mapping profiles? A disadvantage is, that with this approach we load data from the database which is not needed in the end. Another disadvantage is that we then have to implement the logic on several places (for every profile)

Comment: If you use ProjectTo - it will not load not needed properties.

Comment: I know, but I cannot use `ProjectTo` in all cases because I have to do some client side evaluation before mapping the entities to dtos.

Comment: I suggest to play with Automapper, otherwise you have to create several DbContext with own mapping options. Or, what I prefer - create custom projection always.